# Error showing while connecting to localhost

Tags: android, api, post

While trying to connect to the localhost, an error is showing. Please find the error below

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://10.10.14.120:8080/rest/ws/profile_request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the connection like http://10.10.14.120:8080/rest/, if get anything displays on the page your connection is good. then the problem is with your parameters

Answer (score 1):

some time due to  anti virus and firewall can causes this problem. So disable your anti virus and firewall it can solve your problem.

Also make sure http://10.10.14.120:8080/rest/ is working in your mobile browser as well